# Как создать ярлык для файла с помощью python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть программа, которая получает абсолютный путь до файла, как создать ярлык, указывающий на этот файл?

Comment: Что значит «получить»? Создать или что-то другое?

Comment: Получить картинку ялыка

Comment: Что значит картинка ярлыка? Чтобы получить картинку из ярлыка, нужно откуда-то сперва достать сам ярлык. Не все файлы являются ярлыками, и не все файлы имеют какие-то картинки внутри себя, которые можно было бы получить.

Comment: допустим, на рабочем столе есть файл untitled.exe, как получить его ярлык?

Comment: Возвращаемся к первому комментарию — что значит «получить ярлык»?

Comment: создать ярлык этого файла, сори за глупость

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943757

Comment: Спасибо, не мог найти ответ

Comment: @user463291, проголосуйте и примите, пожалуйста, ответ, что решает вашу проблему :)

Answer (score 2):

Ярлык можно создать через `WScript.Shell`, используя библиотеку `pywin32` (`pip install pywin32`):

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch


def create_shortcut(file_name: str, target: str, work_dir: str, arguments: str = ''):
    shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
    shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(file_name)
    shortcut.TargetPath = target
    shortcut.Arguments = arguments
    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = work_dir
    shortcut.save()
```

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/bf2d83ef9d6c1ebd80043be9686c3bc9388f90fd/win_create_shortcut_lnk.py#L11)

```
from pathlib import Path

abs_file_name = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe'
path = Path(abs_file_name)

name = 'My startup python scripts 1'

create_shortcut(
    file_name=f"ConEmu start task '{name}'.lnk",
    target=str(path),
    work_dir=str(path.parent),
    arguments='/cmd {%s} -new_console' % name,
)
```

В чистом виде это выглядит так:

```
create_shortcut(
    file_name=f"ConEmu start task '{name}'.lnk",
    target=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ConEmu\ConEmu.exe',
    work_dir=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ConEmu",
    arguments='/cmd {%s} -new_console' % name,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй воспользоваться функцией [os.symlink](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
os.symlink("/путь к файлу", "/путь для создания ярлыка")
```

Comment: `;` не нужно добавлять в питоне

Comment: Во-первых, симлинк и ярлык — это сильно разные вещи. Во-вторых, в Windows нельзя создать симлинк без прав администратора